# Can figure out how to move to the next record after running a query on button click

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

i am building in visual studio. I have the forms created and i can run the query i built in query designer but when i do my BindingSource.MoveNext() no longer works. i found some code online (Pasted below) but it starts from the first record not the current record. any help is appreciated. Also I am a Novice of the lowest level.

```
Dim current = 0
    current = BindingSource.Position
    TableAdapter1.Fill(DataSet.TABLE)
    BindingSource.Position = Math.Min(current + 1, BindingSource.Count - 1)
```

Query code:

```
Public Function Search() As Task
        Try
            Me.TableAdapter1.QueryName(Me.DataSet.TABLE, CType(TextBox1.Text, Integer))
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return Nothing

    End Function
```

Thanks again,

edit: I think I know why its doing this. The query is only pulling one record. The one that matches the criteria. Is there a way to pull all records and maybe use an if statement to go to the record i am looking for, then look at the rest of the records using the move next command?

Comment: can you provide the method QueryName? Based on my search, I can not find that method. By the way, how do you check if the record is correct or not.

Comment: the method QueryName is the name of the sql query that i created in the query designer. I dont understand what you mean by checking the record, the query retrievs the record and it is shown on screen. it is pulled by the primary key of the database it is connected to.

Comment: how do you check the record, do you use datagridview?

Comment: It is shown on screen with various textboxes